# Vertical spacing of captions in booktabs

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

Both `\abovetopsep` and `\belowbottomsep` are 0.0pt. But for some reason there's extra space between the bottom rule and "my second caption" in the table below.

Q: What is that space? Where does it come from?

Ultimately, I'd like to do the following:

```
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{<the width between the bottom rule and "my second caption">}
```

so that there's some uniformity in the vertical placement of captions above and below tabulars.

Q: Is there another, maybe more standard, method for doing this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{my first caption}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    foo & bar \\
    \midrule
    baz & bog \\
    \bottomrule 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{my second caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tab1]

Comment: `booktabs` has nothing to do with captions.

Comment: Your code features something that's quite unusual: you have only one `tabular` environment (and one `table` environment) but two captions. What are you trying to achieve? One can assign labels to LaTeX captions, which can then be cross-referenced; are you trying to be able to create separate cross-references (e.g., `Table 1` and `Table 2`) to the same floating object? Separately, you may want to develop a style for your paper(s) such that table captions are located either all above or all below the tabular material.

Comment: @Mico. I only did that to demonstrate the difference in spacing between captions above and below a `tabular`. I only intend to have my captions above the `tabular`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ad 1: As egreg has commented, `booktabs` has nothing to do with captions. The standard document classes `article`, `book`, and `report` define the lengths `\abovecaptionskip` (default value: 10pt) and `\belowcaptionskip` (default value: 0pt). `\abovecaptionskip` is responsible for the space in your example.

Ad 2 : Have a look at the [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, especially at section 2.6 *"Skips"* of its manual.

Comment: There are two lengths in `booktabs`, `\abovetopsep` and `\belowbottomsep` that can change the caption spacing. Their default values are zero, but `\abovetopsep` can be set to the same value as `\abovecaptionskip` resulting in the same space for captions above and below a table.

Comment: @lockstep: great suggestion. I'm now using `\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}` to get the desired result.